# how to select a pre-defined value in bootstrap 3 dropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/2955/). It all looks fine however the issue is that instead of having the initial 'Choose' I wanted to have the first option in the dropdown automatically selected. How do I do so?

```
<div class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Pilih Jenis Search <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
        <li><a href="#">Barang</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Toko</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

It seems what this does now is when you select a value from the dropdown, it just goes to the link in the href. Instead what I want is the behavior to be like a select box. But the interface to similar what I have now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Bootstrap dropdown](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns) feature acts as a **menu**. It can be thought of as being similar to the StackOverflow menu.

[image: dropdown example]

From what I understand you want a more traditional [select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select).

[image: select example]

The bootstrap dropdown isn't really supposed to be a replacement for a select. To have a dropdown behave like a select will require some javascript functionality ([AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) or similar would be a great choice).

Bootstrap does come with a [select component](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls), but it doesn't do anything fancy to it.

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nxeWS/3/) shows one approach using Angular.

### HTML

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="searchController">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input id="searchbox" type="text" class="form-control search-query" placeholder="Masukkan produk atau toko yang kamu cari disini">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                {{getSelected()}}
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#" ng-repeat="opt in options track by $index" ng-click="selectOption($index)">{{opt}}</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Javascript

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

var searchController = app.controller("searchController", function($scope) {
    $scope.options = ["Barang", "Toko"];
    $scope.selected = "Pilih Jenis Search";

    $scope.selectOption = function(option) {
        $scope.selected = $scope.options[option];
    }

    $scope.getSelected = function() {
        return $scope.selected;
    }
});
```

Comment: Yup..I am actually looking more of a select.. however I want to style it as a dropdown.. I guess that's the whole question

Comment: Yeah it'd really have to be a new component. I've edited my answer to include a suggestion on how to approach the problem.

Comment: that's exactly what I needed but I don't want to include angular.js just for that. I'd be more than happy to accept your solution if that were a javascript/jQuery solution